# Azure Search Distance filter with variable distance

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Suppose I have the following scenario:

A search UI to allow individuals to find plumbers who are able to service their home location.

When a plumber enters their info into the system, they provide their coordinates and a maximum distance they are willing to travel.

The individual can then enter their home coordinates and should be presented with a list of plumbers who are eligible.

Looking at the Azure Search geo.distance function, I cannot see how to do this. Scenarios where the searcher provides a distance are well covered but not where the distance is different for each search record.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search) provides the following example:

```
$filter=geo.distance(location, geography'POINT(-122.131577 47.678581)') le 10
```

This works correctly but if I try and change the 10 to the maxDistance field, it fails with

> Comparison must be between a field, range variable or function call
>   and a literal value

My requirement seems fairly basic but am now wondering if this is currently possible with Azure Search?

Answer (score 1):

I found an [azure feedback suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/14827626-support-for-geo-distance-function-on-customer-loca) asking for this feature but no news on if/when it will be implemented. Therefore it is safe to assume that this scenario is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Paul's answer, one possible workaround is to use a conservatively large constant value instead of referencing the `maxDistance` field in your `$filter` expression. Then, you can filter the resulting list of plumbers on the client to take each plumber's max distance into account and produce final list of plumbers.

Comment: Definitely an option though discarding results at the client makes paging much more difficult.